# I can't get XFCE terminal to display VIM's colorschemes

Tags: linux, vim, terminal, xfce, xterm

That's what I have in my .bashrc

```
if [ -n "$DISPLAY" -a "$TERM" == "xterm" ]; then
    export TERM=xterm-256color
fi
```

In my .vimrc I have:

```
set t_Co=256
```

*echo $TERM* prints *xterm-256color*

*tput colors* prints *256*

I've also runned a script called *256colors2.pl* and all colors are printed correctly. Still what I see in my terminal is this (that's the "desert" theme):

[image: desert]

Also the colortest.vim file does not display properly:

[image: colortest]

Apparently it only shows the default color palette of my terminal.

Comment: Just to confirm, what does the output of "`:verbose set term?`" (with the question mark as part of the command) say?

Comment: "term=xterm-256color". I don't know what happens. Is xfce terminal overriding the colours?

Comment: It shouldn't be.

Comment: So do you know how to change it?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what's wrong, so I don't.  It shouldn't make any difference, but what happens if you do `:set term=xterm-color` in Vim?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing.

Comment: It might be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492166/how-to-change-xterm-colors-using-xdefaults-file usually colours you see in vim will use Xterm colours.

Comment: possibly also try setting COLORTERM environment variable.

Comment: Was this solved? Maybe post it on vi/vim stack exchange?

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to the xfce terminal preferences, click the Compatibility tab, and make sure the emulation setting is "xterm-256color" and not "xterm"

The basic reason for the issue can be found in this article: 
https://codeyarns.com/2015/03/18/how-to-set-term-to-xterm-256color/

Basically, you need to have VTE or GNOME based terminals set the `term` environment variable before the shell is invoked. The above settings will cause this to happen in the XFCE terminal